# Enable GitHub Actions through REST API

Tags: rest, github, github-actions, github-api

I have an on-prem GitHub instance with an org with many repos. Some seem to have actions Actions disabled:

[image]

However, if I query this through the REST API:

GET https://my.github.example.com/api/v3/repos/myorg/the-repository/actions/permissions results in:

```
{
    "enabled": true,
    "allowed_actions": "selected",
    "selected_actions_url": 
    "https://my.github.example.com/repositories/21251/actions/permissions/selected-actions"
}
```

And even if I try to forcefully enable it, [according to the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4/rest/actions/permissions#enable-a-selected-repository-for-github-actions-in-an-organization):

PUT https://my.github.example.com/api/v3/orgs/myorg/actions/permissions/repositories/the-repository I get:

```
{
    "message": "Conflict",
    "errors": "GitHub Actions is enabled for all repositories",
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/enterprise/3.4/rest/reference/actions#enable-a-selected-repository-for-github-actions-in-an-organization"
}
```

As for the button in the UI (the screenshot above), this works. The code behind it is:

```
<form class="" method="post" action="/myorg/the-repository/actions/enable"> 
   <input class="btn btn-primary my-3" type="submit" value="Enable Actions on this repository">
   <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="asdlkjflasdkjflaskjflasdkjflkasdjf">
</form>
```

However it doesn't post to the REST API but the Web UI (obviously)..